# MOSS 2007 Version History Query

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I need to generate a report that sums the number of files uploaded to a document library, including individual versions.

For example, if I have a document library that contains 20 unique documents, with only two items having more than one version (say two versions each), I'd like to be able to return a report that indicates that there have been 22 uploads.

Is this possible using the built-in MOSS 2007 tools? Do I have to query the database directly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query the database directly. Its not supported.

This is possible using Audit reports. Enable Auditing on library and then you can query the Auditing in sharepoint object model.

Code sample on Item level auditing:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0e4dd1e7-4b1d-4cb1-b906-6d5d272c8e9d&displaylang=en

Enable Auditing:
http://www.shareesblog.com/?p=195